# Central login Site for multiple ASP .Net Web Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm building several App's or Modules (Each got its own Project or might be a solution) and I need to develop a central core module that acts as a configuration App as well as the main login portal and users management (Using the built-in Identity 2.0)

I need a hint or a road map on how I can allow that functionality so when a user requests a specific module (Might be on a completely another URL, Database or Machine), he'll be redirected to the login page and then return back to the requested url. Of course I need to not include the same login mechanics and controllers in each and every project.

PS: I still need to use the normal Identity User Role check in the Applications/Modules like usual.

Comment: Use IdentityServer http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/

Comment: Thank you but I'm restricted to hand crafted solutions.. will keep it in mind meanwhile though.

Comment: Identity server will do what you want, you can still use Asp.Net identity 2.0. Otherwise there are 3rd party solution like auth0, however they are free to an extent then you pay up.

Comment: How it is going to work since identity works per domain or App only by default. Can you explain more?

Comment: Yasser is right. Identity 2.0 won't do what you need 'out of the box'. The issue is that you will be able to login on `Site A` but the way your user login token is signed won't transfer to `Site N`. From what I've read in the past the only way you can do this is by having a duplicated MachneKey across all sites.

Comment: @scgough Identity Server != Identity 2.0. This is achievable with identity server

Comment: I've read something like that. But what about the user activity check and role validation as well as the database along with the main identity logic. Do I have to copy all of them along with the database connection string, or something else is needed to be done to have it centralized completely.

Comment: @12seconds yes, sorry i agree - I was just trying to point out the issues with trying to achieve this via Identity 2.0 out of the box.

Comment: @YasserAkram Identity Server is separate from your web app, it act as a "login portal" per say, then your web app which is set up with identity 2.0 connect to that server. There's alot of example available through GitHub by the creator of identity server

Comment: @YasserAkram Identity != Permission, you keep your role/permission handling on your web application

Comment: @12seconds yes I got it.. well that's not what we wanted. The role and permission is almost deployed and can't just rewrite the Apps to work with a third party like Identity Server

Comment: Not sure why not? Your roles and permission is still part of your web application. Identity server just validate who you say who you are, and provide you a token.

Comment: @12seconds, now everything is in one solution. It has many Areas that acts as Modules. But in the Main Directory we have Central Views And Controllers. We call for permission check both: User.IsInRole("role") and [Authorize(Roles = "role")]. So I'm not sure if we separate the solution into many, how the mechanism will work. I mean what about the Views and Controllers of the Identity 2.0? Still confused about it.

Comment: @12seconds, we have custom Identity 2.0 Views and Controllers by the way, It is based on a ready code that has Groups of Roles. You can consider it as a custom Identity 2.0.

Comment: All I can say is look into identity server and understand what its purpose and how it works. Your implementation on identity 2.0 for your web application stays intact, all you change is mostly the configuration part of it to point to identity server.

Comment: +1 for @12seconds - I think you should look at the component he's mentioned. It sounds like it is the extra layer on top of your existing Identity implementation you need. Also, if you can't achieve your desired results with the code you have then the only solution is to write more code, no?

Comment: @scgough I will, I'm just going to do some more research before. Getting into new stuff is little late now as there is an extra overhead and troubleshooting knowledge required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with [IdentityServer4](http://identityserver.io/)

There is a learning curve here but I decided to go ahead as it will be a better solution in the future.